# Regex identify and strip '.00' in strings

Tags: php, jquery, regex, content-management-system, number-formatting

My users are entering products in their stores, and my *PHP CMS* prints prices as a normal 2 decimal number. My problem is that all of the whole number prices, i.e. `80` are printing as `80.00` - I'd like to only print decimal integers if they exist, so `80.95` prints, but `80.00` only prints as `80`

There are no symbols in the numbers, only periods `.`

I can identify and escape strings server-side at page generation with regular expressions, and I prefer to do this than matching and replacing with jQuery on page load, so is there a regex for `.00` that operates without the period `.` operating as a wildcard? Regex is a weak point for me, so I apologise for posting each time I can't find an answer.

Comment: You can escape the dot in a regex: \. It will then match a dot rather than any symbol. I guess the best solution would be to change the format to display the number correctly without further manipulation, but I don't know PHP enough to help you there.

Comment: Thank you, escaping the . as `\.` has worked a treat :)

Comment: Why not just cast it to int? `num.indexOf('.00') > -1 ? parseInt(num) : num`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something similar to:

```
(\d+)(\.00)
```

and match group 1 to find the digits before the full stop. See the rubular link to play with it interactively.

http://rubular.com/r/fyvdFflctc

Comment: Thank you, it was just a matter of escaping the `.` with `\.00` - I've now replaced all instances of `.00` with nothing and it's worked.